# how do i get the parent key of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am tryion to get the key index based on the value that i am searching in the array. I have the folloeing array:

```
    [0] => Array
                (
                    [n1:ProductWithTermPricingOptions] => Array
                        (
                            [n1:ProductName] => Customer will provide modem
                            [n1:PricingOptions] => Array
                                (
                                    [n1:Priority] => 600
                                    [n1:PricingOptionCode] => LCTL_SA_MDM_NONE_LCTL:NONE:MODEM:IN:CON:SA:na:na:NONE:NONE:-1:-1:NONE:LCTL:NONE:0:na:NONE:A:PO:na:0:NULL:NULL:NULL
                                    [n1:ProductMonthlyCharge] => $0.00
                                    [n1:PromoMonthlyCharge] => $0.00
                                    [n1:ProductActivationCharge] => $0.00
                                    [n1:ProductActivationChargeDescription] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [n1:ContractLength] => Array
                                        (
                                        )


                                        (
                                        )


                                        (
                                        )

                                    [n1:ProductDisclaimer] => Array
                                        (
                                        )


                                )

                        )
```

I need to get the key number where the value "Customer will provide modem" resides in this case it should return number 0 for the key. In other situation it will return a different position. I have tried the following but it returns the key where the value is and not [0]:

```
public static function searchArrayKeybyValue(array $array, $search) {
    foreach ( new RecursiveIteratorIterator ( new RecursiveArrayIterator ( $array ) ) as $key => $value ) {
        if ($search === $value)
            return $key;
    }
    return "N/A";
}
```

Any help is appreciated. My goal here is to put this option in the last position of the array.
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function array_finder($array, $search, $parent_key = false)
{
   foreach ($array as $local_key => $value) {
      $key = ($parent_key === false) ? $local_key : $parent_key;

      if (is_array($value) and ($subsearch = array_finder($value, $search, $key)) !== false) {
         return $subsearch;
      } elseif ($value == $search) {
         return $key;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
echo array_finder($array, 'Customer will provide modem');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the inner key, not the outermost key. Use a normal `foreach` for the outer array, and a recursive iterator for the contents.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
    foreach (new RecursiveIterator($subarray) as $value) {
        if ($value === $search) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your array into a DOMDocument object, child elements actually get visibility on what their parent is, and you can traverse or modify it however you like.  Then just convert it back.  (I understand that those conversion are easier said than done, so if this solution sounds right to you, let me know, and I'll edit this with some helper-functions that can handle that.)